# How to prompt a user for additional input for a Java Hangman game?

Tags: java, loops, input

I have an assignment for a beginner Java course that has asked me to create a class called `Hangman`. The program is supposed to prompt a user (player one) to input a `String`, then print dashes on the screen for each character in the screen. The program then asks a second user (player two) to take guesses one character at a time until either the word has been guessed, or they have six failed attempts. As each correct guess is verified, the corresponding dash in the string is replaced with the correct letter.

At this point I have created code that will scan in a user `String`, and replace the `String` with dashes. The code also prompts the second user for a comparison letter. The code will also replace the first correct guess in the dash String.

The problem I have at this point is that I can't seem to find a way to prompt the user for additional input after the first guess. The program will accept the first correct guess, replace it, and then terminate. I removed a portion of code that checked how many incorrect / correct guesses had been input, because at this point the code would run through constantly incrementing the count and terminate the program. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I have reworked my code to remove unwanted / unnecessary branches.  Here is my updated code.  At this point, I am receiving too many incorrect guesses.  The code is counting every iteration through the array that does not match as incorrect.  I appreciate any help you can offer.

```
public class Hangman 
{


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String word;
    String letter = "";
    boolean gameOver = false;
    int correct = 0;
    int incorrect = 0;
    int index = 0;

    Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Player 1 enter a word: ");
    word = userIn.nextLine();
    String[] wordArray = word.split("");
    int wordLength = word.length();
    String[] wrong = {};
    String[] right = {};
    String[] dashes = new String[wordLength];
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
    {
        dashes[i] = "-";
    }
    for(int i= 0; i < wordLength; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(dashes[i] +" ");
    }
    System.out.println();


    while(incorrect < 6)
    {
        System.out.print("Player 2 enter a letter: ");
        letter = userIn.nextLine();
        letter = letter.toLowerCase();


        if(letter.length() > 1)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: You have entered more than one letter.");
            System.out.print("Player 2 enter a letter: ");
            letter = userIn.nextLine();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
        {
            if( wordArray[i].equals(letter))
            {   
                dashes[i] = letter;
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                for( i= 0; i < wordLength; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(dashes[i] +" ");
                }
                correct++;
            }
            else
            {
                incorrect++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(correct == wordLength)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You Win!!");
        System.out.println();
    }
    if(incorrect == 6)
    {
        System.out.println("You Lose.");
        System.out.println("The word was " +word);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try googling your exact question. TONS of results come up

Comment: Your correct and incorrect fields track the number of correct and incorrect guesses by player 2, correct? so incorrect + correct = totalGuesses. Hint: while totalGuesses <= 6... ???... PROFIT!

Comment: Thanks Brian, I did some searching, but nothing had answered my questions as of yet.  I did not word my question the same way I have here, so I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

So, that's a hefty amount of code. And I see some interesting decisions all over the place. So since you're learning I'll help you help yourself.

Before taking on an application like this you should think about your logic first (psuedo-code) before actually coding. So for a hangman game you probably want something like:

```
player 1 enters phrase
while wrong_guesses < max_incorrect:
    prompt player 2 for a letter
    check the phrase for that letter
    if found
        replace dashes with the letter
    else
        wrong_guesses++
    print status message
```

Just glancing at your code I can see multiple places where you're asking for new input. This means you are not effectively using your loops. Your application has a lot of unnecessary branches and cleaning it up will help you debug. As an exercise, you can walk through your code and write its' psuedo-code, then compare it to mine.

Good luck!

**Update**:

With respect to the new and much improved code, your check loop is wrong. It should look more like this:

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
{
    if( wordArray[i].equals(letter))
    {
        found = true;
        // replace dashes, and you don't need to loop here, 
        // do it after the check for better efficiency
    }
}
//Outside of the loop
if (!found)
{
    incorrect++;
}

//Print the current status here then
```

Also, your check for only 1 letter can be subverted (enter aa, then aa again). That block should be:

```
if(letter.length() > 1)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR: You have entered more than one letter.");
    System.out.print("Player 2 enter a letter: ");
    //letter = userIn.nextLine();
    continue; //This tells java to restart the loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tony, I will go through my code and write a pseudo code version to see where I stand.  I will write back later after I have completed this.

Comment: Hi Tony, I wrote the pseudo code and I see how much I complicated things.  I have reorganized, and deleted code as needed to better fit the pseudo you suggested.  I still have a problem though.  When I run the code, the incorrect and correct flags are not stopping the program.  I am left with a message that states the user has won the game, followed with the user losing the game.  It seems like the loop is checking each character in the array against the guessed letter.  So I end up having multiple incorrect guesses for each letter guessed.  I am not sure how to change this, can you help?

Comment: It sounds like your `wrong_guesses++` is incorrectly in the loop that scans the phrase. When checking to see if the guessed letter is in the phrase make sure you wait till you scan the entire phrase. The best suggestion I can give you is to use Eclipse's debugger and step through your code line by line. Perhaps update the snippet in your question with your new code also! =)

Comment: Thanks Tony! I put the new code up now, and am looking through to determine where to put my check statements.